# How to add my app to "share page" of IE for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

There is "share page" option in IE for wp8, I want to add my app to that list. So, that my app can receive the content of the page or the url of the page. Is that possible and if yes, how to do that. If not, is there any alternative way.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is not exposed for Windows Phone 8. This is possible with WP8.1 by enabling the Share Target functionality within your app. Check out the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871373%28v=win.10%29.aspx), especially [the Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871367.aspx), and this [sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782/view/SourceCode#content).

The short of it is to add the Declaration to the manifest file, define the files you support, and listen to the [Application.OnShareTargetActivated method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onsharetargetactivated.aspx) event.

Comment: Is there any work-around? is it available for Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Comment: I added info about phone 8.1